# Gatsby to generate pages when a new variable is served from Contentful CMS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

So I built a Gatsby blog with products, and it can programmatically generate pages for every product. I want to add to this project so that it also generates pages for product categories. Each category page will display all products in that category.
The content is served from Contentful CMS.

Is this possible? to add a second layout template and create such pages?

```
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, boundActionCreators }) => {
    const { createPage } = boundActionCreators

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const blogPost = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-post.js')
        const categoryPage = path.resolve('./src/templates/category-post.js')

        resolve(
            graphql(
                `
            {
              allContentfulBlog(limit: 200) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    categories
                    mainTitle
                    mainImg {
                      id
                    }
                    mainText {
                      childMarkdownRemark {
                        excerpt
                      }
                    }
                    slug
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          `
            )
                .then(result => {
                    if (result.errors) {
                        console.log(result.errors)
                        reject(result.errors)
                    }

                    result.data.allContentfulBlog.edges.forEach(edge => {
                        createPage({
                            path: edge.node.slug,
                            component: blogPost,
                            context: {
                                slug: edge.node.slug,
                            },
                        })
                    })
                    return
                })
                .then(result => {
                    result.forEach(category => {
                        createPage({
                            path: '/' + edge.node.category,
                            component: categoryPage,
                            context: {
                                slug: edge.node.category,
                            },
                        })
                    })
                })
        )
    })
}
```

The first .then() method in the promise works just fine, and my idea is to simply add a second .then(), with the categories pages's template.

Terminal shows:
[image: terminal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert this after products pages loop but you don't have data for categories. It's possible to collect it from products but it would be quirky workaround.

You need separate query, separate promise and to compose promises (`.all()`) at top level.

Comment: I have extracted some code trying to make the snippet shorter. I think i have kinds done what you suggested, except the .all part for promises. You have anything i can study on how to use promises like that? you can find the code i have right now here http://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/161015/ Apparently it destroys the product pages i already had(amongs some other issues)

Comment: second exports overwrites first one?  You need to compose two promises into one - search for examples/tutorial /docs.